# IOS limit to threads created and run one-at-a-time

Tags: ios, multithreading

I have an IPAD program designed to torture the thread creation process,
which is failing unexpectedly after a few thousand iterations of a 
process like this:

> pthread_create [a thread that does nothing and exits very quickly]
>   sleep(100);

Eventually, pthread_create fails with error 35 "too many threads"

The failure occurs, eventually, no matter how long the sleep interval.

Is there some arbitrary limit to threads over time, or is there some 
resource I'm likely to be consuming without realizing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either call `pthread_join` from another thread to reclaim the resources, or call `pthread_detach` to indicate that the resources should be reclaimed automatically. Like unix processes, threads have a result that needs to be reaped before it can completely go away.

Comment: Thanks.  I misinterpreted the doc for pthread_create to think that join was optional.